# dotnetnuke <customErrors mode="Off"/>

Tags: asp.net, web-config, dotnetnuke, custom-errors

I have successfully installed dotnetnuke 6 on localhost and is working fine but when i uploaded it to shared hosting webserver it is giving error

here is the link http://www.pakwindow.com/pages/

```
 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

when i open the web.config file it is already

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" >
```

now i dont understand what is happening and no more details is available 
may be the cause of the error is i have uploaded the site not in root folder ie httpdocs

rather i have made a subfolder named pages and there i have uploaded the site 
now i cannot upload the site on root without testing and how can i test a site in page folder

any suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errormessage is saying that you should set the customerrors to mode "off" if you want to see any details of the error.

Like this:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

If you do that you will probably see a describing error message and be able to fix it.

With the mode you have now "RemoteOnly" you will only see the detailed error from localhost.